# How to download an attachment from an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, download

I am developing a web application which uses a .NET MVC back end and HTML with JavaScript and AJAX on the front end.

One page has a feature where the page makes an AJAX call to the .NET controller which then returns a JSON object. Based on the contents of this object, the browser downloads a PDF file. This is implemented so that the same .NET controller has another method which returns a stream, and the JavaScript code then makes a full page request (not an AJAX call in this case) to that method, which causes the browser to offer to view or save the PDF file.

However, this seems like extra work, particularly since the PDF file is already available when the first AJAX call returns. I could just as easily dump its contents into the returned JSON object, encoded in Base64 if necessary. But my question is, how can I then trigger the download in the browser in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your ajax callback, create an `<a>` tag with the `href` attribute set to the base64 string and then click on the tag.

```
.then((response) => {
   var pdf = response.data;
   if(!pdf) { return; }

   var a = document.createElement("a");
   a.href = `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}`；
   a.download = "filename.pdf";
   a.click();
})
```

Although I would recommend twitching your controller to make it return the pdf file directly with `Content-Type` set to `application/pdf` and replace the ajax request with a simple JavaScript statement like `window.location="/api/pdf/username"`